# Generating divs with same class, but want to change styling individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got some script which first generates a div, then sets the background to a random hex colour. Currently, when it sets the background colour of the div, it sets the background colour for all divs of that class.

How do I get it to set the colour of only the div it is creating and leave the others alone?

http://jsfiddle.net/rb2v1bu5/

```
function makeThing(){
    var back = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var hex = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex1 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex2 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex3 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex4 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex5 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];

    var rand = "#" + hex + hex1 + hex2 + hex3 + hex4 + hex5;    

    $('body')
    .append("<div class='thing'></div>");

    $('.thing').css('background',rand);
}


setInterval(makeThing,1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three ways you can do this, I think the first solution is probably the fastest because it's just string building. The second solution is the one I would do because it feels the cleanest to me (representing your node as an object and changing a property on it, feels nice and object-oriented to me) and the last solution, or any solution, in which you're querying the DOM is bound to be the slowest, so even though it's just a one liner I would avoid doing it.

**Method 1:** You can just attach a `style` property to your div as you make it:

```
function makeThing(){
    var back = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var hex = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex1 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex2 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex3 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex4 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    var hex5 = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];

    var rand = "#" + hex + hex1 + hex2 + hex3 + hex4 + hex5;    

    $('body')
    .append("<div class='thing' style='background: "+rand+"'></div>");
}


setInterval(makeThing,1000);
```

---

**Method 2:** Build your element and set the background in javascript before you insert it into the DOM, just replace:

```
$('body').append("<div class='thing'></div>");
$('.thing').css('background',rand);
```

with:

```
var div = $("<div class='thing'></div>");
div.css('background',rand);
$('body').append(div);
```

---

**Method 3:** a pure jquery solution, change `$('.thing').css('background',rand)` to `$('.thing:last').css('background',rand)`

Comment: It's an overkill to use `:last` and let JS parse all over the whole document searching for all those elements to only than apply a CSS to `:last` when it can be done immediately. What you call *Object Oriented* is inaccurate in that case. *"OR a pure jQuery solution"* ...the jQuery you showed before was also *pure*. When dealing with in-memory elements, it's good to first apply all the CSS to that element before inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I explained in my answer that the last solution is the slowest, so we're in agreement. We're also in agreement that it's good to set CSS before injecting into the DOM so my second approach remains my favourite, and it is still the most "OOP" solution because you're representing your node as an object, unlike the first solution where it's just a string....

Comment: I'd keep the answer strong and concise with only the Good parts. Without the *bad* parts to avoid confusion (since only explained in the last paragraph of your A.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I moved my suggestion to the top - I think it's useful not only to know what you should do, but also useful to know what you should *avoid* doing :)

Comment: Looks a bit better now but still... *`"set the background in javascript"`* what does this means? jQ *is* Javascript, but you use no so-called *Vanilla* JS

Answer (score 1):

just use the `last` method

so:

```
$('.thing').last().css('background',rand);
```

[see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb2v1bu5/1/)

it will always only change the last element with class `thing`, which should be the last one you appended.

Answer (score 1):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rb2v1bu5/4/)***

- Create a `rand` helper function (you can pass `min` and `max` arguments)
- Use `RGB` or `HSL` colors. **It's simpler**.
- Create new elements using `$("<element />", {properties})`. **It's simpler**

```js
function rand(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); }

function makeThing(){
  $("<div />", {
    class : "thing",
    appendTo : "body",
    css: { background: "rgb("+rand(0,255)+", "+rand(0,255)+", "+rand(0,255)+")" }
  });
}

setInterval(makeThing,1000);
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.thing{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reference for your created `<div>` before you add it to the dom:

```
var thing = $('<div class="thing"></div>');
thing.appendTo('body').css('background', randomColor);
```